# Building a tokenizer in java

Tags: java

I have a problem with my code. I'm trying learn java/programming by building a tokenizer that can handle different grammars(words, arithmetic, dots, comma...etc) sent in regex when the Tokenizer object is instaniated.

My class works for the first word, but after the first loop the `matcher.find()` doesn't find a match and throw an "java.lang.IllegalStateException: No match found"

i.e., I get a print of "Hello" but not of "my" and "friend". What am I doing wrong?

My class, Tokenizer, looks like this

```
public class Tokenizer {
  private Pattern pattern;
  private Matcher matcher;
  private String text;;
  Tokenizer(String text) {
    text.input = text.trim();
  }
  public Tokenizer(String regex, String text) {
    this(text);
    pattern = Pattern.compile(regex);
    matcher = pattern.matcher(this.input);
    while(matcher.find()) {
      String match = matcher.group();
      System.out.println(match);
    }
  }
```

I instantiate the class and send the text "Hello my friend".

```java
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String regex = "\\G\\w+";
    String testString = "Hello my friend.";
    Tokenizer tokenizer = new Tokenizer(regex, testString);
  }
```

Comment: So tested the regular expression in https://regex101.com and it only matched the first word.  If I remove `\\G` it matched each word

Comment: `text.input = text.trim()` does not make sense. I think you have some typos, `private String text` should probably be `private String input` and `text.input = text.trim()` should then be `this.input = text.trim()`?

Answer (score 0):

So, when I dumped your code into a IDE I had some issues

```
public class Tokenizer {
  private Pattern pattern;
  private Matcher matcher;
  private String text;;
  Tokenizer(String text) {
    // This won't compile at all
    text.input = text.trim();
  }

  public Tokenizer(String regex, String text) {
    this(text);
    // this.text may be null, depending on how the
    // constructor works (which, when I was trying
    // to fix it, I did accidentally :/
    pattern = Pattern.compile(regex);
    matcher = pattern.matcher(this.input);
    while(matcher.find()) {
      String match = matcher.group();
      System.out.println(match);
    }
  }
}
```

So, I fixed your constructor so it would compile and it works

```
public class Tokenizer {

    private Pattern pattern;
    private Matcher matcher;
    private String text;

    Tokenizer(String text) {
        this.text = text.trim();
    }

    public Tokenizer(String regex, String text) {
        this(text);
        System.out.println(this.text);
        pattern = Pattern.compile(regex);
        matcher = pattern.matcher(this.text);
        while (matcher.find()) {
            String match = matcher.group();
            System.out.println(match);
        }
    }
}
```

Although, I might be tempted to change the class to work something more like...

```
public class Tokenizer {

    private String text;

    Tokenizer(String text) {
        this.text = text.trim();
    }
    
    public List<String> regularExpressionMatches(String regexp) {
        System.out.println(this.text);
        Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(regexp);
        Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(this.text);
        List<String> matches = new ArrayList<>(16);
        while (matcher.find()) {
            String match = matcher.group();
            matches.add(match);
        }
        
        return matches;
    }
}
```

Since you're not capturing the regular expression input (via the constructor), I would consider this a transient workflow (that is something that the class might do) and move all the functionality into it's own method, so that it's properly isolated.  I'd then return all the matches, so the caller can do something with it.

This might allow you to add "other" types of matching algorithms based on you needs.

It's just a thought ;)